# Two submit buttons in one condition

Tags: php, post, conditional-statements

I have a problem with "condition in condition". Both conditions are dependent on submit button in form. Situation: user clicks on first submit button -> the 3 methods of Class are called -> third method "creates" another form with another submit button. This submit button is subject of the second important condition. When the second submit button is pressed, there are 2 method to be call. But nothing happend. The fourth Method and fifth Method should be follows on the previous methods. How I can solve this? I hope that the problem description is not confusing. There is a little code example too. Thanks.

```
$c = new Class;

 if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
   $c->firstMethod();
   $c->secondMethod();

   if($c->thirdMethod() != false) {
     echo ".. the second form with submit button will be here ...";
   }

   if(isset($_POST['button_of_second_form'])) {
     $c->fourthMethod();
     $c->fifthMethod();
   }
 }
```

Comment: So you're wanting to collect data in different stages?

Comment: how about you move the condition of the button of the second form outside the condition of the button of the first form... but I'm not sure if I completely get your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when the second form is submitted it will not pass from the first condition because first you are checking:

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {....
```

and inside this condition block you are checking the 2nd form. If you can include the hidden value of `button` in the 2nd form then it will get pass from the first condition but then you have to take care of the first & second method to not run.

Comment: Thank You for answer. I know what is the problem, but I dont know how this situation solve. I need returned values from previous methods pass to fourthMethod and fifthMethod. Can you little more explain your idea whith hidden value please ?

Comment: Ok, in first condition check: `if(isset($_POST['button']) || isset($_POST['hidden_value'])) {` then further, not to run the first method and second method if hidden value `if(!isset($_POST['hidden_value'])){ $c->firstMethod();  $c->secondMethod();}` then where you are doing echo of second form add `<input type="hidden" name="hidden_value" value="1" />` so that it should pass first condition.